# Rocket Thrust Equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

I am doing the math required to find the thrust of a rocket engine (more specifically backwards, I have the thrust required and I am designing the engine).

In my looking over the equations I have found on the NASA website:

http://spaceflightsystems.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/rktthsum.html

$$F={\dot {m}}*Ve+(Pe-Po)*Ae$$

In this equation:
        ${\dot {m}}$ = Mass flow rate
        $Ve$ = Exit velocity
        $Pe$ = Exit pressure
        $Po$ = Chamber pressure
        $Ae$ = Exit area

It seems to me that if the ambient pressure and exit pressure are equal, that the equation would just be:

$F={\dot {m}}*Ve$

Would this be the correct because $(Pe-Po)*Ae $ is then zero?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Are you asking whether $a-b=0$ for $a=b$ or is your question really whether the equation you found is correct? For the latter question, it might be of advantage to edit your post to (i) include a reference and (ii) explain the variables you are using

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158750/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, with $V_e$ the velocity of the gases at the nozzle exit.