# Understanding rocket equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rocket-science

I'm doing a science project where I have to explain the physics behind a trip to an exoplanet and I also have to explain about rocket equations while doing so. I know that a trip to an exoplanet is pretty much impossible, but it more has to be the theoretical part of the physics. And my problem is with the rocket equation. So far I have this simple equation:

$$\Delta v=v_e \ln\left(\dfrac{M}{M - m_R}\right)$$

This should give the maximum velocity of a rocket with the total mass $M$ and the fuel mass $m_R$. But I'm kind of unsure what to do about $v_e$. I believe it supposed to be the gravitational pull, but I need the rocket equation for a rocket that's already in space so I don't have to think about getting out of earth's atmosphere and all that. So I'm kind of stuck here. I would also like to know the time that it takes the rocket to get to the planet, which is 16 light years away or $1.514 \times 10^{14}$ kilometres away.

I hope this makes sense. Physics isn't my strong suit, so any help would be appreciated.

** Edit **
Okay, so I think I get it a little more now. Say we have a rocket that needs to transport a load with the mass of 500 kg.

$$M-m_R=500\ kg$$

But we still need to get a speed that's somewhere near the speed of light of possible (This is only theoretical of course). So if we say 1/8 the speed of light which is around $37000000\ m/s$ or $3.7\cdot 10^{7}\ m/s$. Now to get a rocket moving that fast, we would need a proper engine. And according to the link @BowlOfRed provided, the most effective spacecraft propulsion method is a Nuclear photonic rocket which has an exhaust velocity of roughly $2.99\cdot 10^{8}\ m/s$. Can we then just add the load amount and the exhaust velocity value to the equation and find how big the fuel motor has to be? I know that I'm doing something wrong about this, since the equation gives a strange and small number when you find $M$. And the Nuclear photonic rocket method probably isn't a very realistic method, but again, my projekt is mostly theoretical and I'm only trying to find a way that it, in theory, should be possible to travel to an exoplanet.

Comment: Where did you get this equation? Did they explain what $v_e$ is?

Comment: That is the [Tsiolkovsky equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) and $v_e$ is the exhaust velocity i.e. the speed the exaust gas leaves to rocket motor.

Comment: @JohnRennie so $v_e$ is calculated by how big the area where the gas leaves is and the speed of it?

Comment: $v_e$ is just the speed of the exhaust gas. The area of the exhaust nozzle doesn't matter. Or are you asking about the relation between $v_e$ and the volumetric flow rate?

Comment: $v_e$ for some real (and theoretical) engine technologies mentioned at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_propulsion#Table_of_methods

Comment: @JohnRennie No just about $v_e$ alone. So if I were to use one of the methods listed in the link that BowlOfRed supplied, how would I go about that? For example if I used the Nuclear Photonic Rocket method with an exhaust velocity of $299,792\ km/s$, could I just change $v_e$ to that number?

Comment: The [*Why are rockets so big?* question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88145/25301) discusses what $v_e$ is: the exhaust velocity. Human-made rockets typically have $v_e\sim4\,{\rm km/s}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that after reading the comments you understand that $v_e$ is the exit velocity of the fuel, you need to further understand what $\Delta v$ is. It's the *change in velocity* of the spacecraft. For real missions this is *not* simply the maximum velocity of the craft.

When you want to visit an exoplanet and *return*, you need to distribute your $\Delta v$ onto several parts of the trip:

1. Accelerate to leave Earth
2. Brake to not fly past the exoplanet
3. Accelerate to leave exoplanet
4. Brake to no fly past Earth or cause a crater, which we call *lithobraking* :-)

Aerobraking in an atmosphere may relax some of these $\Delta v$ requirements, as will swing-bys/gravity-assists along the way. See also this cool [$\Delta v$ map of the solar system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy3Cj.png).

So if your fuel allows for a $\Delta v$ of say 40km/s, your actual travelling speed is going to be considerably lower.

And we haven't talked about *staging* yet, which also changes things a bit.

Now with nuclear fuel exiting near the speed of light, indeed, fuel mass is quite low. There's a factor of 30.000 compared to the $v_e$ of a chemical reaction (generously taken as 10km/s).
If I'm not mistaken, a matter/antimatter rocket is ideal, after solving the problem of getting that nasty kind of [unobtainium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium) in measurable quantities.