# Is there a limit to the mass of a chemical rocket leaving for Earth orbit in a single stage?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, rocket-science, propulsion

Is there a limit to the mass of a chemical rocket leaving for **earth orbit** in a single stage?

Payload, fuel, structure ... all things considered.

Comment: Leaving to get *in* the orbit of the earth or escaping from earth?

Comment: Related, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/why-do-rockets-have-multiple-stages?rq=1

Comment: Practically (are there size limitations?), yes, but they're not given by the equation you cite.

Comment: For a rocket in the gravitational field of earth the important factor is the rate at which you burn fuel (source: Kleppner&Kolenkow *An Introduction to Mechanics* the chapter about momentum. Rocket motion section).

Comment: Leaving to get into orbit. Good additional reading

Comment: Although there is no theoretical limit to the mass of a single-stage rocket, multi-stage rockets are required for efficiency and practicality.  Malabarba's answer to this related question may help you understand the variables: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/why-do-rockets-have-multiple-stages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard limit to the mass, but practically speaking, for existing rocket fuels, $v_e\,\ln(\frac{m_0}{m_f})$ is limited to speeds well below escape velocity. Maximum fuel fractions are of the order of perhaps 98% or so, since you are going to need some mass for the structure of the rocket and its engines. You could achieve very high $v_e$ with non-chemical rockets, but those typically require a lot more structure. Bottom line is that at the current state of the art, you cannot really make it into orbit with a single-stage rocket, unless you have an air-breathing engine so you can take the oxidant part of your fuel from the atmosphere.